# regex to get three numbers from string and put them into variable in bash

Tags: regex, bash, curl

I'm using curl to get a json (no line break) result from a website, now I need to pick up two numbers from entire strings.

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" https://example.com -d ""
```

returned result is:

```
{"rows":[{"description":"Persistence: Maximum wait time (milliseconds)","name":"maxWaitTime","value":10000.0},{"description":"Persistence: Maximum number of items","name":"sizeThreshold","value":1000.0},{"description":"DB: Number of threads","name":"numberOfThreads","value":10.0}]}
```

I need to pickup those 3 numbers and put them into variables in bash script.

Description before each number, from "description" to "value", are fixed.

in case timeout happens and curl return error 28, "-1" should be assigned to variables.

I have tried approach like:

```
awk '/"name":"numberOfThreads","value":(.*)},/{print $0}'
```

but it returns entire line.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: Look into `jq` for JSON parsing.  It is built for it.

Comment: `awk` is not the right tool for `json` parsing; `jq` is. Having said that, `awk` returns the entire record with `$0`. Individual fields are returned in `$1`, `$2`, etc and by default, they are separated with whitespace. So, your `awk` attempt here is not going to help you anyway.

Comment: Your JSON appears to be broken. Can you check if its a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is missing a comma between the last two `{objects}` in your `[array]`. I would be very surprised to learn that cURL output invalid json, but I will show you how to use `jq` to retrieve values from this data structure:

Note: `jq` will work regardless of whether the structure is compact (your example) or pretty printed (below)

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "description": "Persistence: Maximum wait time (milliseconds)",
      "name": "maxWaitTime",
      "value": 10000
    },
    {
      "description": "Persistence: Maximum number of items",
      "name": "sizeThreshold",
      "value": 1000
    },
    {
      "description": "DB: Number of threads",
      "name": "numberOfThreads",
      "value": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

We want to filter all the objects in the array `rows`, so we will first strip the array by name, then retrieve "value" by key:

```
$ jq '.rows[].value' file
10000
1000
10
```

Now you could iterate over these results in a while loop, but the clever move is to use Bash 4's `mapfile` and process substitution `<()` to create a Bash array:

```
$ mapfile -t Array < <(jq '.rows[].value' file)
$ declare -p Array
declare -a Array=([0]="10000" [1]="1000" [2]="10")
```

Comment: Thank you. yes, you are right, I missed a "," in original message. It's a typo when I was trying to simplify the message.

Comment: A further question. my current code is: curl http://sample.com|jq '.rows[].value'. but when I try to convert it to an array, it always complain "redirection unexpected". I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. It seems like (jq xxx) format doesn't work on Ubuntu.

Comment: figured out the issue, I forgot to update shell to /bin/bash